# Why did The Doctor (Doctor Who) have matches in his pocket?

Tags: doctor-who

The first 1963 four part story "An unearthly child" has the Time Lord, his grandchild and two of her teachers back in caveman days. Two factions are in conflict over the secret of fire. Ian is showing one bunch how to rub some sticks together but the Doctor walks past, leans down and strikes a match to the kindling. A quote ensues - " he makes fire come from his fingers"
My question is:- Why would an alien with a high tech TARDIS carry around a box of matches?

Comment: Because the doctor is always prepared.

Comment: “Why would an alien with a high tech TARDIS carry around a box of matches?” — to start fires?

Comment: In answer to the comments, The doctor is always prepared - he's not Batman with his utility belt, he didn't know they were gonna end up in prehistoric times and need a fire..  why would he want to start fires? He travels in a nice box with climate control . I don't carry matches around just in case one day I think "time to start a fire". Maybe it was just an accepted thing in 1963. I know in the film Peter Cushing had the Doctor smoking a pipe but I don't remember seeing any TV timelords smoke

Comment: The answer may have to do with pragmatism.  Granted, the Doctor has access to the most advanced of technologies, but how advanced do you need to be to make fire?  A lighter can run out of fuel or the flint might break.  A lazer fire started needs power.  But matches only need the match and the box.  Matches are in many ways more reliable than other ways of starting fire.

Comment: Another thought.  Simply using matches already blew the minds of the cavemen.  Imagine how they'd react to a 60th century Zippo?

Comment: During Tennant's run in the episode "The Doctor's Daughter" he had a wind up toy mouse!!!! They're the pockets of a Timelord... I wouldn't be surprised about anything in there.

Comment: “why would he want to start fires?” — to impress cavemen?

Comment: I'd like some video evidence both of the Doctor lighting a fire with matches and the quote "He makes fire come from his fingers", because I seem to recall the Doctor having _lost_ his matches and therefore _can't_ make fire, and there is no such quote in the "[An Unearthly Child](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/1-1.htm)" transcript.

Comment: Aargh! History playing tricks on my memory perhaps? Nevertheless your bit from the transcripts clearly shows that the Doctor carried matches but couldn't find them when he needed them

Answer (score 9):

To light his pipe.

We see the scene where the prehistoric men first see the Doctor light fire here (although it's not super-clear that matches were involved):

[s01e02 - An Unearthly Child - Part 2 - The Cave of Skulls](http://dai.ly/x3hxuzp?start=617)

Your memory of the situation seems to be slightly off in that he wasn't intending to show off, but rather was observed (by someone who does come to believe, and tell others, that he makes fire from his fingers), and perhaps there were other, later, scenes where he did something similar to what you remember, but this first instance reveals the answer: to light his pipe.

Keep in mind that although he is an alien with a hi-tech TARDIS, he both had an appreciation for and lived on Earth, at that time masquerading as a human.  Bringing forth a self-lighting pipe or some technological doo-dad would have seemed out of place in 1960s society, so, if he wanted to light a pipe, particularly when he was out and about in modern day society (such as might be required for getting Susan registered in school), carrying matches would be a good habit to get into.

Why he might like to light a pipe would be a separate question.

Comment: And may I add, using a cigarette lighter to light a pipe is a real pita.

Comment: Fairy Nuff . Faulty memories. I knew there was matches but really can't recall him smoking a pipe on the series

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Smoking_pipe) the Doctor smoked a pipe in the first story, An Unearthly Child

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe he carried matches because the sonic screwdriver doesn't work on wood.  <strike>Which begs the question, why don't the more current doctors carry matches?</strike>

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Also, could you please provide some explanation of why the screwdriver might not work on wood?

Comment: @Mithrandir, I have no idea why the screwdriver doesn't work on wood.  It has been a long standing "joke" during the reboot seasons.  Immediately after the nearly magical sonic screwdriver has saved them from a complex and nearly un-escapable danger, they come across a simple wooden door and the Doctor has no canned solution.  Time for the companion to spring to the rescue.